# is a space before `!important` important in some cases, and if so, when? And why?

Tags: css

I've been experimenting with [`scssphp`](http://leafo.net/scssphp/), a PHP SCSS compiler, and specifically its *compressed* formatter.

This outputs something like (notice the extra whitespaces and the semicolon before the closed curly brace)

```
.navbar{margin-bottom  :0px !important;margin-top    :4px;}
```

and so I thought of implementing this *small modification* to shave a few bits off the resulting code.

<sup><sup>I know it makes little sense, in that I will save at most some percents in size; and I'm removing low-entropy information, which means that once I gzcompress it, the savings will be even smaller; while the modification will then have to be maintained. But it seemed easy enough, and harmless enough, and I... sort of did it for the lulz.</sup></sup>

```
4225    public function format($block) {
4226        ob_start();
4227        this->block($block);
4228        $out = ob_get_clean();
4229---     return $out;                        // OLD
4229+++     return $this->postprocess($out);    // NEW
4230    }
```

The postprocessing function is dummy on the parent formatter, above:

```
4232    protected function postprocess($text) {
4233        return $text;
4234    }
```

...while in `scss_formatter_compressed` I perform some replacements:

```
+++ from line 4343:

protected function postprocess($text) {
    $xlat = array(
        '#\\s+(:\\d)#'          => '\\1',
        '#;}#'                  => '}',
        '#\\s+(!important)#'    => '\\1', 
    );
    return preg_replace(
        array_keys($xlat),
        array_values($xlat),
        $text);
}
```

Now the output is:

```
.navbar{margin-bottom:0px!important;margin-top:2px}
```

...and for simple SCSSs it works. I have tested it on a large and complicated SCSS hierarchy, and some elements break.

I have the **sensation** that it involves the `!important` clause. I have done a not really extensive research, and found [this](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/37) on the YUI-compressor site, where on the one hand they conclude

> @tml @namanyayg Could you provide any examples where stripping a space
>   before '!important' leads to a broken styling?
>
> We got the similar request in
>   https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css but without a test case it's
>   not possible to verify if you made a mistake or if there is a very
>   specific case where the space has to be there.
>
> According to our tests **it is OK to get rid of it. What's more such
>   code has been used in production for couple years now without any
>   issues.**

On the other hand the OP *had* some problems, and they *seemed* to be related to a space before `!important`.

Now if it is a CSS-standards issue I want to fix my take on scssphp; if it is a problem of that one SCSS, I of course want my SCSS files fixed. Given the sheer size and complexity of the folder in question, I thought to ask here before delving into its unplumbed depths.

Comment: IIRC this is an IE issue but I can't find the answer I posted about it because SO search sucks at handling terms like "!important".

Comment: If you are testing on other browsers then it shouldn't be an issue - the space between the end of a property value and the ! is always optional in standard CSS.

Comment: For what it's worth, the validator says it is valid to omit the space before `!important`.  The official Ruby Sass compiler always leaves a space, even in compressed mode.  Keep in mind that IE has historically been bad about parsing valid CSS (anyone remember when you could hide styles from IE5 or 6 by removing spaces in selectors?  eg. `.foo+.bar`), so there is probably a reason why Sass has chosen to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No space is required. According to [CSS syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#consume-a-declaration),

> 4. While the [current input token](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#current-input-token) is anything other than an [<EOF-token>](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#typedef-eof-token), append it to the declaration’s value and [consume
>      the next input token](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#consume-the-next-input-token).
> 5. If the last two non-[<whitespace-token>](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#typedef-whitespace-token)s in the declaration’s value are a [<delim-token>](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#typedef-delim-token) with the value "!" followed by an
>      [<ident-token>](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#typedef-ident-token) with a value that is an [ASCII case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#ascii-case-insensitive)
>      match for "important", remove them from the declaration’s value and
>      set the declaration’s *important* flag to true.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't really answer the question:  are there browsers that choke when the whitespace is omitted?  Does said browser choke every time the whitespace is omitted?

Comment: Since minified css (css without spaces) is a staple in high traffic Web sites, we can say with confidence that the only need for space in css is for legibility purposes. Do some validation, and check if you're using the right encoding.

Comment: I've since moved this to production code, and today it broke again. **I confirm it's an IE issue**, but it is not present (at least not today) on Microsoft Edge. On IE, it went away disabling the space-eating regex and came back re-enabling it, but crazily enough, it worked on *some* CSS. It's only with large CSSes that it seems to appear!