# How to use calc in external css style sheet with !important

Tags: wordpress, css

I'm customizing a wordpress theme with an external style sheet.
When fixing fonts and stuff I have to use `!important` to overrule existing setups for different elements.

I've found that awesome calc-line that fixes responsive issues.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/

it lets you set up a minimal and maximum font size for diff viewports.
and you would use it with
`@media screen and (min-width: $min-vw)` etc...

```
font-size: calc([minimum size] + ([maximum size] - [minimum size]) * ((100vw - [minimum viewport width]) / ([maximum viewport width] - [minimum viewport width])));
```

for example:

```
font-size: calc(14px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
```

Here's my question:

normally, I use the expression !important somehow like that:
`font-size: 16px!important;`

How do I combine the calc line with the !important expression?

I tried
`font-size: calc(14px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)))!important;`, 
but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I usually insert a space before `!important` - that might help in this situation.

Comment: @Johannes, I am not sure, but maybe no space is required. According to CSS syntax? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31143078/622813